# Android x86 will not connect to the internet

Tags: android-x86

I am using Android x86 4.4 RC2 (Dual-Boot not Virtual) and I can't connect to the internet. Whenever I click Wi-Fi, it stays on "Turning on Wi-Fi" and the Wi-Fi button is grayed out like the option is not available. I opened the terminal and used netcfg to see if the Wi-Fi driver (wlan0) was on but it wasn't so I turned it on by typing "netcfg wlan0 up" and it was up so I went back to the Wi-Fi settings but it still wasn't working. What do I do to enable Wi-Fi?

Comment: I'm going to guess that your WiFi chip is unsupported. What model of chip is in your computer?

Comment: I have Realtek RTL8187SE Wireless 802.11b/g 54Mbps PCIE Network Adapter